# Create a menu frame that can scroll off the page

Tags: html, scroll, frames

I currently have a site with a menu in a frame on the left and the content in a frame on the on the right. I want to move the menu frame to the top of the page (horizontal instead of vertical), but I want the menu to move up off the visible page when scrolling on a large content page, as though the menu was part of the content.

Note: I do not want to render the menu on the content page as all the current links target specific frames/windows and I would like to not have to render the menu on every request.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether it's possible to scroll a frame off the page, it is. Just use an IFrame. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

Just be aware that if you had lengthy dropdowns in  your vertical frames, they may get truncated in a horizontal "menu" in an iframe of limited height.

Comment: Will an iframe not have to live on the content frame? If a user then clicks on a link, the whole page would have to be reloaded.If you mean that the content should be in an iframe, then an iframe cannot be resized.

Comment: @Peter: An iframe *can* be resized, but you have to do it programatically. You don't get that for "free" as you do with regular frames.